# Apple Developer Account - AdHoc Provisioning

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Im curious to know whether apple developer account ($99/ year) facilitates to create adhoc provisioning profiles.

The scenario behind is that, i want to distribute my app among testers before submitting to the App Store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

> **Ad Hoc Distribution**
>
> With Ad Hoc distribution, you can share your app
>   with up to 100 iOS devices via email or your server.

Comment: I would add that Apple now offers a beta testing program called TestFlight, which allows up to 1000 testers. You would need an app store provisioning profile to deploy to TestFlight. It is also available with individual developer program.

Comment: Hi Yairsz, Thanks for the information. I just read, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html really helpful!